# GridView in LinearLayout

Tags: java, android

Можно ли использовать gridview в linearlayout/
Ставлю, вроде отображает,а содержимого нету!

Comment: Добавьте код разметки к вопросу и код, как вы заполняете GridView.

Comment: любые лэйауты можно использовать в любых лэйаутах. покажите разметку

Answer (score 0):

В LinearLayout использовать GridLayout можно.

Comment: @AndrioSkur я дал ответ на вопрос вроде?

Answer (score 0):

Использовать gridview в linearlayout можно. Скорее всего у вас нет содержимого в gridview. Проверьте размеры, поставьте match_parent